# Firefox 27.0 or 27.1 is not showing updated css style. Bug?

Tags: firefox

I think i got this bug after updating firefox to version 27.0 or currently 27.1
The thing is, that whatewer changes i am making in css, firefox just ignore them and in inspector i checked,that it's showing rules that dose not exist anymore. Even IE7 works better. I alredy had this bug couple days ago, reinstalling did the job. But now it's back. It's seems like, tahat only after couple hours of working, after PC is turned on, this bug appears. 
Has anyone had a similar problem? A possible solution?

Comment: Tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @tonjo Yes. Fresh as baby